# Changing fixed content on jQuery tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Having trouble with jQuery `$('#tabs').tabs();` As seen here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/4/) the content that contains an external php file

```
 <li class="files">

                <a href="msg_inbox.php">Compose Message</a>
            </li>
```

is constantly being shown even when other tabs are hovered upon.I want to eventually change all the anchor tags and link them to other php files. I would like to understand why this fixed content is so and how to eliminate this problem as well as an other tips one may have. I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can fix the "Compose Message" text by changing it's anchor href to "#one" but I don't really get what you are trying to do?

Comment: Since the `#one` div isn't mentioned in any of the tab `li`s, it's treated as normal page content, not tab content. So it appears all the time.

Comment: The problem with this is actually a bit upstream. You are using a jQuery plugin to control nav elements...which is fine, but not the way you are trying to do it. Let's say what you were trying to do did work, clicking msg_inbox.php would cause a browser refresh and reset the DOM and your nav(unless you hardcode each pages nav--not advised). That being said, it looks like you are trying to construct some sort of app. If that is the case you should really be loading your server-side data into a view using some MV* framework like Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`event:'mouseover'`

With

`event:'click'`

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/qTXnN/5/

### Update

Thats because `<a href="msg_inbox.php">` should be `<a href="#one">`

Comment: Notice how "Compose Now" still shows up when you click on the other tabs.

Comment: @Shmiddty Thats because `<a href="msg_inbox.php"` should be `<a href="#one"`